# Role based authentication depending on group in google cloud firestore rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to secure an app in which users can manage their bands. The users can be part of multiple bands and therefore can have different roles depending on which band they are currently editing. The role is stored in a Map in the Band document.

Is there any way to apply this to firestore rules? So that the function getRole() will not only work for "bands" but also for other collections containing an idBand field (like "events")

My Setup looks like this:
[image: Firestore Setup]

I tried to do something like this:

```
function getRole(){
    return get(/databases/{database}/documents/bands/request.resource.data.idBand/members/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role
}

match /bands/{document=**}  {
    allow read;
  allow write: if getRole() == 'OWNER';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
// Rules for a band document and its subcollections
match /bands/{bandID}{

  function isBandOwner(userID){ 
    // Determine if user is a band owner
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/bands/$(bandID)).data.members[userID].role == 'OWNER';
  }

  // Anyone can read
  allow read;

  // Only authenticated owners can write to band doc
  allow write: if request.auth != null && isBandOwner(request.auth.uid);

   // Rules for all of a band's subcollections
     match /{document=**}{

     // Anyone can read
     allow read;

     // Only authenticated owners can write to a band's subcollections
     allow write: if request.auth != null && isBandOwner(request.auth.uid);

   }        
}
```

To try it out, let's also restrict reads and try to read some test documents:

```
allow read: if isBandOwner(request.auth.uid);
```

[Set up Firebase Auth with Google Sign-in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk) and try to read from Cloud Firestore:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.9/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  //Sign in with Google
  var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
  var token = result.credential.accessToken;
  // The signed-in user info.
  var user = result.user;
  console.log(`UserId: ${user.uid}`)

  // Try reading Firestore docs
  var db = firebase.firestore();

    // Disable deprecated features
    db.settings({
      timestampsInSnapshots: true
    });

    // This doc has members.[my-uid].role = "OWNER"
    // Read should succeed
    db.doc("bands/abc").get().then((doc) => {
            console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data().name}`);
    });

    // This doc has members.[my-uid].role = "BANDMEMBER"
    // Read should fail
    db.doc("bands/def").get().then((doc) => {
            console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data().name}`);
    });
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // The email of the user's account used.
  var email = error.email;
  // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
  var credential = error.credential;
  // ...
  console.log('error login');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This answers part of my question, as i need not only limitate the access to "bands" per bandID. But also for other tables like "events". Is there any way to get the bandID from the request and pass it as a parameter to "isBandOwner" ? (So that the function would work for every kind of table that contains an idBand field)

If not? Do you think it would be a good Idea to implement "events" as a subcollection of "bands" to achieve the desired security? 
Again, thank you so much for helping us out :)

Comment: You're welcome! They rules above will work if `events` is a sub-collection of bands.

Comment: As for whether or not that's what you want, it depends on the queries you need.

If you are interested in just a single band's events, then a sub-collection makes sense.

 If you also want to list all the bands in a single event, then you might want an `events` collection with each `event` document keeping track of all the participating bands.

Comment: Alright, i will check it out :)
Is it possible to get a bandID from the request to a users document ? Because i need to limit the access to my users collection too.

Comment: I tried your Answer on my server but it doesn't work :/ There must be something wrong with the isBandOwner function. Any Idea?

Comment: Hmm, I believe it's working for me. Did you try it in the simulator or in your app and with what request? Another thing that comes to mind is that you might need a separate case for `create` if users are creating bands themselves.

Comment: Ok i readdressed this problem just now and i was able to make it work in your simulator. The problem is: The same request that works in the simulator, doesn't work in our app?? (get bands/uid)

Comment: *In the App it works with*:
allow read: if request.auth != null;

*...as soon as i insert the following, it only works in the simulator*:
allow read: if request.auth != null && isBandOwner(request.auth.uid);

Comment: I'll try it out again. Does the rule for `write` work as expected?

Comment: Tried it out and worked as expected. Can you verify that auth is set up correctly for you app and add some sample queries to your question? Updating my answer with the code  I used to verify.

Comment: Hi, thank yo so much for your effort. The get request is working now :)! (The error was on my side due to a typo). But i'm still having problems with the following request:
database.collection("bands").where("name" ,"==", "asd").get().then((docs) => {
            docs.forEach((doc) => {
                console.log(`${doc.id}`);
            })
        });